# How to solve $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9x^2+18x+2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I solve 
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9x^2+18x+2}} ?$$

I feel like I'm missing a basic step? Something to do with substitution?

Comment: Do completing the square then use a $tan(u)$ substitution

Comment: If you need more just ask

Comment: @HenryLee what is the $tan(u)$ substitution?

Comment: $x=\tan(u)$, its a trig sub

Comment: Let $x=\tan(u)$ with some rearrangement go make sure that you get $\tan^2(x)+1$

Comment: @HenryLee I've tried this now but I end up with $9+18sin(u)cos(u)-7cos^2(u)$

Comment: @HenryLee Do you think you could write a step by step answer but going maybe just 1 step after the $tan^2(x)+1$?

Comment: Added an answer now. On further inspection tan(u) cannot be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2+18x+2}}\,dx$$
$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{(3x+3)^2-7}}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{(3x+3)^2}{7}-1}}\,dx$$
But in this case since it is a minus sign I think you would use a hyperbolic substitution

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

[image: Part 3]

Sorry for the photos I got bored of typing out mathjax on a phone

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that$$9x^2+18x+2=(3x+3)^2-7.$$In other words, do the substitution $3x+3=y$ and $3\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dy$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: This should be a comment, or a small hint.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9x^2+18x+2}}=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{9(x+1)^2-7}}$$
then let $3(x+1)=\sqrt{7}\cosh u$. Therfore
$$\int \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\frac{\sqrt{7}\sinh u}{\sinh u}du=\dfrac13u+C=\color{blue}{\dfrac{1}{3}\operatorname{arccosh}\dfrac{3x+3}{\sqrt{7}}+C}$$

---

Another substitution is $3(x+1)=\sqrt{7}\sec u$. Then
\begin{align}
\int \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{7}}\frac{\sqrt{7}\tan u\sec u}{\tan u}du
&= \dfrac13\int \sec u du+C \\
&= \dfrac{1}{3}\ln|\sec u+\tan u|+C \\
&= \color{blue}{\dfrac13\ln|3x+3+\sqrt{9x^2+18x+2}|+C}
\end{align}

Comment: Is there any difference one would do a hyperbolic substitution rather than a normal trig sub? Extra points for obscurity?

Comment: It doesn't make difference when you use hyperbolic function or trigs.

Comment: @Sorfosh IMO, hyperbolic functions are entire functions and $\sinh$ is bijective, so using hyperbolic functions has a lower chance of leading to errors due to the problem of injectivity of substitution or singularities.